# count all possible interpretations of array of digits

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let 1 represent ‘A’, 2 represents ‘B’, etc. Given a digit sequence, count the number of possible decodings of the given digit sequence.An empty digit sequence is considered to have one decoding. It may be assumed that the input contains valid digits from 0 to 9 and there are no leading 0’s, no extra trailing 0’s and no two or more consecutive 0’s.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int helper(string s,int k,int* memo)
{   int result = 0;
    if( k==0 )
        return 1;
    int t = s.length() - k;
    if( s[t] == '0')
        return 0;
    if(memo[k]!=-1)
        return memo[k];
     result = helper(s,k-1,memo);
    if(k>=2 &&((s[t]==1 ||s[t]==2)&&s[t+1]<7 ))
        result+=helper(s,k-2,memo);
      memo[k]=result;
     return result;
}
 int num_ways(string s,int k)
 {
     int memo[40];
     for(int i = 0;i<40;i++)
     {
         memo[i] = -1;
     }
    cout<<helper(s,k,memo)<<"\n";
 }

int main() {
    int num_ways(string s,int k);
    int helper(string s,int k,int* memo);
    //code
    int t = 0,len=0;
    string s;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
       cin>>len;
       for(int i = 0;i<len;i++)
       cin>>s[i];
       num_ways(s,len);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is always giving one.

Comment: This seems like a great time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: A hint though: When you define a container (like a `std::string` object) it starts out *empty*. Any indexing of it will be *out of bounds* and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: my mistake was i didnt used ' 3 '  to compare with character array in line  f(k>=2 &&((s[t]==1 ||s[t]==2)&&s[t+1]<7 )) @Someprogrammerdude i understood your point.Article made realise mistake.

Comment: While that probably helps, your first and biggest mistake is `cin>>s[i]` when `s` is empty. I suggest you wait with declaring `s` until after you read `len`, then you can do `string s(len, 0);` to define `s` with a specific size.

Comment: I tried doing the same i.e just declared and then tried to input by indexing the first element.And when i printed it some absurd character came which looked like pin a box.But I am not able to figure out how did it worked here.I printed after getting input in this code ,the output was correct. @Someprogrammerdude